# JavaScript: Calling variable functions of an initiated class (packet-handler)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a server/client model with Node.JS and want to call a function of an already instantiated class by using a variable packet-ID and handle the incoming server-packets by different functions. Therefore I put the packet-ids as properties of the `PacketMethods` object and the function to call as the value of each packet-id-property. However in this example when `ServerList()` is called, it's not a member of the initiated `Client` Class and therefore `this.socket` is undefined.

How could I call the packet-handling functions so that they're a member of the `Client`?

```
function Client (...)
{
  this.socket = new net.Socket();

  ...
}

Client.prototype.HandlePacket = function(blocks)
{
  try {
    var sPacket = new WRPacket(blocks);
    var PacketMethods = {
      4352 : this.ServerList
      4351 : this.LoginResponse
    }

    if(PacketMethods.hasOwnProperty(sPacket._packetid))
      PacketMethods[sPacket._packetid](sPacket);
    else
      console.log('Unhandled Packet: '+sPacket._packetid);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("Error at Packet-Handler:\n"+err);
  }
}

Client.prototype.ServerList = function(Packet) 
{
  console.log('Serverlist received ...');
  ...
  this.socket.end();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the `PacketMethods` to store the names of your methods, then call them with the correct context:

```
var PacketMethods = {
    4352 : 'ServerList'
    4351 : 'LoginResponse'
};

if (PacketMethods.hasOwnProperty(sPacket._packetid)) {
    var method = PacketMethods[sPacket._packetid];
    this[method](sPacket);
}
```

Comment: That's even better, as it doesn't create many function on each `HandlePacket` invocation. And you can move the `PacketMethods` declaration outside of the method, into a static scope.

Comment: Oh wow this was easy! Thanks to both of you! It's good to know about bind though - still learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the methods to your instance:

```
var PacketMethods = {
  4352 : this.ServerList.bind(this),
  4351 : this.LoginResponse.bind(this)
}
```